STM32MCU flash download failed
I have a problem and would like to ask for advice. The microcontroller board I have does not have a UART port, but the pins are reserved, so I want to use the TTL to USB  for  debugging. Everything was normal before the wiring was done, Keil could download the program, and the LED test program was also fine. But after I wired and powered on the microcontroller, the microcontroller broke down. The error message showed" too many errors" and" flash download failed "Cortex _M4"". I don't know what the reason is. The picture is an example I found.
enter image description here
I tested it and found that the power supply was normal (my microcontroller power supply is  3.3V); I used the internal crystal oscillator; reset and boot0 were also 3.3V; Keil could detect the chip ID, but it could not download.
After canceling the verify in the flash download, it showed that the downloading was successful, but the program did not run correctly. I also tried operations such as erasing the entire chip, but it did not succeed. I checked the manual for the microcontroller pins, and the voltage resistance "min (VDD, VDDA, VDDIO2, VDDUSB) + 4.0", at least it is close to 6V.

This sounds like an electronics problem rather than software.  You might want to try on electronics.stackexchange.com, however you will need to show the schematic before and after "the wiring was done", otherwise you are just asking people to guess.

Can you explain how you initially connected the board to your computer (when it was working) and how you do it now? What's the exact MCU (and board) you are using? What pins do you connect to?

The MCU I use is STM32L4R9, the board is made by myself, the pins are PB6&PB7,  these two pins are UART1 of L4. I use a USB to TTL cable to connect to the board, the USB end is connected to computer, and the TTL end is connected to PB6&PB7,and the GND pin of the board respectively.
